# How to scrape keywords that change every time?

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, rss

I am trying to scrape a keyword in an xml document with BeautifulSoup but am unsure how to do so.

The xml document contains "Central Index Key," which changes each time for each document scraped. How would I be able to log the central index key for every unique xml document I scrape?

A sample is below. I want to log the string "0001773427" in this example:

```
<SEC-DOCUMENT>0001104659-22-079974.txt : 20220715
<SEC-HEADER>0001104659-22-079974.hdr.sgml : 20220715
<ACCEPTANCE-DATETIME>20220715060341
ACCESSION NUMBER:       0001104659-22-079974
CONFORMED SUBMISSION TYPE:  8-K
PUBLIC DOCUMENT COUNT:      14
CONFORMED PERIOD OF REPORT: 20220714
ITEM INFORMATION:       Departure of Directors or Certain Officers; Election of Directors; Appointment of Certain Officers: Compensatory Arrangements of Certain Officers
ITEM INFORMATION:       Financial Statements and Exhibits
FILED AS OF DATE:       20220715
DATE AS OF CHANGE:      20220715

FILER:

    COMPANY DATA:   
        COMPANY CONFORMED NAME:         SpringWorks Therapeutics, Inc.
        CENTRAL INDEX KEY:          0001773427
        STANDARD INDUSTRIAL CLASSIFICATION: BIOLOGICAL PRODUCTS (NO DIAGNOSTIC SUBSTANCES) [2836]
        IRS NUMBER:             000000000
        STATE OF INCORPORATION:         DE
        FISCAL YEAR END:            1231

    FILING VALUES:
        FORM TYPE:      8-K
        SEC ACT:        1934 Act
        SEC FILE NUMBER:    001-39044
        FILM NUMBER:        221084206

    BUSINESS ADDRESS:   
        STREET 1:       100 WASHINGTON BOULEVARD
        CITY:           STAMFORD
        STATE:          CT
        ZIP:            06902
        BUSINESS PHONE:     203-883-9490

    MAIL ADDRESS:   
        STREET 1:       100 WASHINGTON BOULEVARD
        CITY:           STAMFORD
        STATE:          CT
        ZIP:            06902
</SEC-HEADER>
```

Comment: Post the url you are trying to scrape.

Comment: @platipus_on_fire_333 https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1773427/000110465922079974/0001104659-22-079974.txt

Comment: Please can you provide a couple more urls you will be scraping. Is this the only detail you need? Is the index key of fixed length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Sample Company Name AdminContact@<sample company domain>.com'}
r = requests.get('https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1773427/000110465922079974/0001104659-22-079974.txt', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
print([x.strip().replace('\t', ' ') for x in soup.text.splitlines() if 'CENTRAL INDEX KEY:' in x ][0])
```

This will return:

```
CENTRAL INDEX KEY:   0001773427
```

If you only want the key:

```
print([x.replace('\t', ' ') for x in soup.text.splitlines() if 'CENTRAL INDEX KEY:' in x ][0].split(':')[1].strip())
```

Comment: How would this work if I want to find the filename in this example? <DOCUMENT>
<TYPE>8-K
<SEQUENCE>1
<FILENAME>tm2221127d1_8k.htm
<DESCRIPTION>FORM 8-K
<TEXT>

Comment: You can do `print(soup.filename.text.split('\n')[0])`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your document is SGML, not XML.  XPath requires that your document be XML.

Use a different tool or convert your document to XML if you wish to use XPath.  An example of a SGML to XML converter is [sx](http://www.jclark.com/sp/sx.htm) by [James Clark](http://www.jclark.com/).

Comment: Would there be a way to read this document without converting it to XML? Or is this necessary?

Comment: You might be able to hack something together on an ad hoc basis via string manipulation (such as is done in [@platipus_on_fire_333's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72998517/290085)).  If you find such an approach to lack the robustness or flexibility you require, converting to XML would allow you to leverage highly capable, robust, modern tools.